# Using time machine backup data from newly installed OS X Lion

Tags: snow-leopard, macos, time-machine

I need to replace my HDD to SDD, and I think of upgrading to OS X Lion.
Can I use my old backup in time machine HDD from Snow Leopard when I have clean install with Mac OS X Lion? I mean, can I open time machine in newly installed Mac OS X Lion to copy all the necessary files backup in Snow Leopard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Lion Migration Assistant has had no problems for me to restore users and applications from recent Snow Leopard external disks. I was pulling from Time Machine, but it shouldn't matter if it's just a bootable drive or has many point-in-time versions typical of Time Machine.